# SQL Server 2012 Exclude a value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm teaching myself SQL, and I ran into a scenario that I cannot seem to solve. Please any help.

I have a table called `tblRecord` with a column called `BuyerID`, in this case there are two `BuyerIDS`, and I have another table called `tblOffer` that has a column that is called `InsertedID`.

What I'm trying to do is if the two declared `BuyerID` from `tblRecord` are not the same as `tbloffer` in `insertedID`, then exclude that value.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(DISTINCT r.RecordID) AS Lines,
    COUNT(r.RecordID) AS Offers,
    MONTH(r1.Submitdate) AS M,
    DAY(r1.submitdate) AS D
FROM    
    tblReq r1
INNER JOIN 
    tblRecord r ON r1.ReqID = r.ReqID
INNER JOIN 
    tblOffer o ON r.RecordID = o.RecordID
WHERE   
    r.BuyerID IN (36, 160499)
    AND o.OfferTypeID IN (1, 3)
    AND r1.Submitted = 1
    AND r1.SubmitDate >= '2015-07-01'
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(r1.Submitdate), DAY(r1.submitdate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of your question is correct and you are only wanting to return records from tbloffer if there are also records in tblRecord matching those buyer ids, then you should be able to add a clause within your join so that it will only return those records.

I think this will cover it for you.

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT r.RecordID) AS Lines
      , COUNT(r.RecordID) AS Offers
      , MONTH(r1.Submitdate) AS M
      , DAY(r1.submitdate) AS D
FROM    tblReq r1
        INNER JOIN tblRecord r
            ON r1.ReqID = r.ReqID
        INNER JOIN tblOffer o
            ON r.RecordID = o.RecordID
            AND r.BuyerID = o.InsertedID
WHERE   r.BuyerID IN (36, 160499)
        AND o.OfferTypeID IN (1, 3)
        AND r1.Submitted = 1
        AND r1.SubmitDate >= '2015-07-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(r1.Submitdate)
      , DAY(r1.submitdate);
```

Hopefully I am understanding your question correctly and this is able to help you.

Comment: thank you @mskinner , it works but there are sometimes null values. is there a way to return null values

Comment: I think it would depend on your dataset but it is possible that changing  AND r.BuyerID = o.InsertedID to  AND (r.BuyerID = o.InsertedID or o.InsertedID is NULL) might get it for you.

Comment: that works also @mskinner. Thank you so muchhhhh !